# Need to create a table in MS Access with calculated field

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2016

PART 1: I need to create a table in MS Access where I just Want 2 columns - A and B.
A is a fixed data field (and will never change) but B is a calculated field (for each row in column A) (I have the formulas for all the rows) which gets data from another Query table in MS Access. Is it possible to create such table? If not, then is there any other way as to how this can be done?

Part 2: This calculated data (column B) is already present in 3-4 Forms in Access. Is it possible to extract this data from all the forms in one table ?

Needs help here as its the 1st time I am creating something in MS Access.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: It is rarely a good idea to store calculated values in a table in a database - you would normally calculate them as and when needed, either in a query or in a form/report.

Comment: can it be calculated I a report ? can you please tell me how ? and if in a form, then how to export that form ?

Comment: In a form or report you would just add a new control (normally a text box), and set the `ControlSource` to be something like `=Field1*0.25` or whatever your formula is.